# IE8 Keeps Breaking My Columns

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, frontend

I'm working on a new website - http://cravezilla.com - which runs on WordPress. I've optimized the site for Chrome, Mozilla, Safari and IE9+. However, on IE8 the columns of my site get all thrown off, and I'm having trouble figuring out why?

I've attached a screenshot of my IE8 preview. Is there something I could include in the CSS to fix this problem?

Here's the image:
[image]

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css file

```
.tri-block:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using box-sizing property which is not supported by IE8. Thing is that you have a wrapper div for those 3 elements with fixed width of 950px. And you specify the width of each element 33.3% and padding 8px. It works with box-sizing because padding is not added to the width. And as IE doesnt have that method and adds the padding to the width you get 33.3% + 33.3% + 33.3% + padding values which is wider than 950px fixed size and that results in third element floating to the new row.

I suggest you remove the box-sizing attribute and set fixed width to those divs to around 300px. It should be on line 483 in your css file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. I'll go test these out. Thanks!

Comment: Box-sizing is pretty cool though. It maybe better to leave it in and target IE8.

Comment: That is true Scott. He could do use special css for ie only and leave this as it is for firefox or other browsers.

Comment: Does using the following code make sense?

.tri-block:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
    }

What would the special CSS for IE be then? Thanks.